# Trying to merge two json using python dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to merge two json stored in python dictionaries. Here, the first dictionary is the parent into which the second dictionary gets merged into. In reality, the second dictionary represents a second line in a TSV file that holds the next record of a json array.
My program is trying to read the TSV file line by line and merging them into one single nested json.
Let us consider the two dictionaries:
Parent dictionary `dict1: {"CA": [{"Marin": [{"zip":1}], "population":10000}]}`
and,
`dict2: {"CA": {"Marin": {"zip":2}}}`

**Note**: `dict1` is the source-of-truth with regards to the correct json structure.

Here, as you can see, I would like to append the `zip: 2` into the Marin county of California state.

Here is my merge code:

```
class MyClass:
    # merges two lines containing json arrays inside nested json
    def merge_lines(dict1: dict, dict2: dict) -> dict:
      for key in dict1:
        if key in dict2:
            if isinstance(dict1[key], dict):
                MyClass.merge_lines(dict1[key], dict2[key])
            elif isinstance(dict1[key], list):
                to_be_merged_list = [dict2[key]]
                dict1[key].extend(to_be_merged_list)
      return dict1
```

Below is how I am trying to test:

```
def test_nested_json_arrays(self):
   d1 = {"CA": [{"Marin": [{"zip":1}], "population":10000}]}
   d2 = {"CA": {"Marin": {"zip":2}}}
   expected_result = {"CA": [{"Marin": [{"zip":1}, {"zip":2}], "population":1000}]}
   actual = MyClass.merge_lines(d1, d2)
   assert expected_result == actual
```

However, I am getting the below result:

```
E      AssertionError: assert {'CA': [{'Mar...tion': 1000}]} == {'CA': [{'Mari... {'zip': 2}}]}
E        Differing items:
E        {'CA': [{'Marin': [{'zip': 1}, {'zip': 2}], 'population': 1000}]} != {'CA': [{'Marin': [{'zip': 1}], 'population': 10000}, {'Marin': {'zip': 2}}]}
E        Full diff:
E        - {'CA': [{'Marin': [{'zip': 1}, {'zip': 2}], 'population': 1000}]}
E        + {'CA': [{'Marin': [{'zip': 1}], 'population': 10000}, {'Marin': {'zip': 2}}]}
```

Can someone help me figure out the changes required in the code to fix this?
**Note**: *the field names are not constant and this can apply to any combination of country, state, county, zip and other nested attributes.*

Comment: What is wrong with "the below result"?  What result did you want?

Comment: I want it like this: `{'CA': [{'Marin': [{'zip': 1}, {'zip': 2}], 'population': 1000}]}` .. the `{'zip':2}` should be with 'Marin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more generic approach, where `d1` is updated with changes contained in `d2`.
Of course, you should provide more examples of updates from `d2` to see if my solution works in all cases.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

d1 = {"CA": [{"Marin": [{"zip": 1}], "population": 10000}]}
d2 = {"CA": {"Marin": {"zip": 2}}}


# read update data from d2 and append new values to d1
def update(d1, d2):
    for key, value in d2.items():
        if key in d1:
            for key1, value1 in value.items():
                if key1 in d1[key][0]:
                    d1[key][0][key1].append(value1)
                else:
                    d1[key][0][key1] = [value1]
        else:
            d1[key] = [value]

    return d1


print(update(d1, d2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dict1 = {"CA": [{"Marin": [{"zip":1}], "population":10000}]}
dict2 = {"CA": {"Marin": {"zip":2}}}
```

Looking at `dict2`:

- You are given `dict2`, containing key `k` (in this case `k = "CA"`)
- `dict2[k]` itself is a dictionary, that contains one (or more) key (`c = "Marin"`) - value (`z`) pair(s)
- `z` now is the dictionary that you care about.

Looking at `dict1`:

- For each element `county_info` in `dict1[k]`, you care about the one that has a key `c`.
- The value at this key (`county_info[c]`) is a *list*, to which you  want to *append* `z`

So let's do that:

```
def merge_lines(dict1, dict2):
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        for c, z in v.items():
            # Find the element of dict1[k] that has the key c:
            for county_info in dict1[k]:
                if c in county_info:
                    county_info[c].append(z)
                    break
```

Since the function modifies `dict1` in-place, running `merge_lines(dict1, dict2)` gives us a modified `dict1` that looks like what you expect:

```
{'CA': [{'Marin': [{'zip': 1}, {'zip': 2}], 'population': 10000}]}
```